# scala.sys.process.Process throws RuntimeException

Tags: scala

I'm trying to get diff of two directories recursively and to register them as a github issues.

If the directories has a few files, scala.sys.process.Process works as I expect.

```
➜  Desktop  ls -la 
(snip)
drwxr-xr-x@  5 garbagetown  staff   170 Sep 19 22:53 2.1.5
drwxr-xr-x@  5 garbagetown  staff   170 Sep 19 11:26 2.2.0
(snip)
➜  Desktop  ls -la 2.1.5/style 
(snip)
-rw-r--r--@ 1 garbagetown  staff   1206 Sep 19 22:53 book.css
-rw-r--r--@ 1 garbagetown  staff    278 Sep 19 22:53 external.png
-rw-r--r--@ 1 garbagetown  staff    175 Sep 19 22:53 header-pattern.png
-rw-r--r--@ 1 garbagetown  staff  12985 Sep 19 22:53 main.css

➜  Desktop  scala
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.3 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_21).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> import scala.sys.process.Process
import scala.sys.process.Process

scala> Process("diff 2.1.5/style 2.2.0/style").!!
res0: String = ""
```

But the directories has many files and dirs, scala.sys.process.Process throws RuntimeException as below.

```
➜  Desktop  ls -la 2.1.5/manual 
(snip)
-rw-r--r--@  1 garbagetown  staff   9139 Sep 19 22:53 Highlights.md
-rw-r--r--@  1 garbagetown  staff   2737 Sep 19 22:53 Home.md
-rw-r--r--@  1 garbagetown  staff   8444 Sep 19 22:53 Migration.md
-rw-r--r--@  1 garbagetown  staff  15202 Sep 19 22:53 Modules.md
-rw-r--r--@  1 garbagetown  staff    670 Sep 19 22:53 User-Groups-around-the-World.md
-rw-r--r--@  1 garbagetown  staff    937 Sep 19 22:53 _Sidebar.md
drwxr-xr-x@  3 garbagetown  staff    102 Sep 19 22:53 about
drwxr-xr-x@  7 garbagetown  staff    238 Sep 19 22:53 book
drwxr-xr-x@  8 garbagetown  staff    272 Sep 19 22:53 detailledTopics
drwxr-xr-x@  9 garbagetown  staff    306 Sep 19 22:53 gettingStarted
drwxr-xr-x@  9 garbagetown  staff    306 Sep 19 22:53 hacking
drwxr-xr-x@  6 garbagetown  staff    204 Sep 19 22:53 javaGuide
drwxr-xr-x@ 16 garbagetown  staff    544 Sep 19 22:53 sandbox
drwxr-xr-x@  7 garbagetown  staff    238 Sep 19 22:53 scalaGuide

➜  Desktop  scala 
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.3 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_21).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> import scala.sys.process.Process
import scala.sys.process.Process

scala> Process("diff 2.1.5/manual 2.2.0/manual").!!
java.lang.RuntimeException: Nonzero exit value: 1
    at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
    at scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilderImpl$AbstractBuilder.slurp(ProcessBuilderImpl.scala:131)
    at scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilderImpl$AbstractBuilder.$bang$bang(ProcessBuilderImpl.scala:101)
    at .<init>(<console>:9)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at .<init>(<console>:7)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at $print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:734)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.loadAndRun(IMain.scala:983)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.loadAndRunReq$1(IMain.scala:573)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:604)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:568)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.reallyInterpret$1(ILoop.scala:756)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.interpretStartingWith(ILoop.scala:801)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.command(ILoop.scala:713)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.processLine$1(ILoop.scala:577)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.innerLoop$1(ILoop.scala:584)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.loop(ILoop.scala:587)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(ILoop.scala:878)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:833)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:833)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.process(ILoop.scala:833)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.runTarget$1(MainGenericRunner.scala:83)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.process(MainGenericRunner.scala:96)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner$.main(MainGenericRunner.scala:105)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.main(MainGenericRunner.scala)
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`diff` has a slightly unconventional way of communicating an exit status. Usually POSIX utils return 0 on success and non-zero on error. Diff returns 0 if there are no differences found, and 1 if differences were found, etc. `Process` thinks that it was an error in execution and throws an exception. So you need to work around that issue.

One way to do it is to use this method instead ([doc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.3/index.html#scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilder)):

```
 abstract def lines_!(log: ProcessLogger): Stream[String]
```

It does not throw on non-zero error status.

For example:

```
Process("diff 2.1.5/manual 2.2.0/manual").lines_!.foreach(println)
```

Comment: Oh, great! I've solved the problem by the way you suggested. Thanks!

Comment: `.lines_!` is deprecated in favor of `.lineStream_!`